# Pre launch report, trying to track down kotlin API error from JVM backtrace

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I have my first pre launch report from Android Studio, I have a bunch of unsupported API errors, eg ...

> API (unsupported) Warning Issue 1 of 10 Called 3 times during testing API

> Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mIsChildViewEnabled:Z
> Stack trace #1
> StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mIsChildViewEnabled:Z
> StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mIsChildViewEnabled:Z
> at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
> at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.(DropDownListView.java:123)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.(MenuPopupWindow.java:147)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow.createDropDownListView(MenuPopupWindow.java:80)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1178)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:663)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:181)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:208)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:792)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:11)
> at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.n(UiControllerImpl.java:6)
> at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.m(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
> at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:6)
> at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:15)
> at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Unknown Source:9)
> at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:1)
> at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:4)
> at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:4)
> at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(Unknown Source:137)
> at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(Unknown Source:4)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

So as I understand it I am useing APIs that are not listed as "officially supported" in the latest Android and so may be withdrawn at any point.I am struggleing to work out from the JVM backtrace what it the issue in my kotlin code, which APIs, from the above I would guess its AbsListView but I am not using this in my app, can anyone give me any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be coming from `androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView`, which is Google's own code. [This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176921658) is for Google to fix matters.

There is nothing that you need to do.